# Polynomial Interpolation and Error Bound

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation

Problem:
Use the Lagrange interpolating polynomial of degree three or less and four digit chopping arithmetic to approximate cos(.750) using the following values. Find an error bound for the approximation.
\begin{align}
\cos(.6980) = 0.7661 \\
\cos(.7330) = 0.7432 \\
\cos(.7680) = 0.7193 \\
\cos(.8030) = 0.6946 \\
\end{align}
The actual value of $\cos(.7500) = 0.7317$ (to four decimal places). Explain the discrepancy between the actual error and the error bound.

---

Solution:
The approximation of $\cos(.7500)$ is $0.7313$. The actual error is $0.0004$, and an error bound is $2.7 × 10^{-8}$. The discrepancy is due to the fact that the data are given only to four decimal places.

---

Can anyone help me figure out the intermediary steps from the problem to solution?

Comment: This problem is not reproducible in the stated form. In my try to reconstruct the error I obtained 0.7317 also as interpolated value, using 4-digit chopping after every elementary operation, the claimed large error was not found.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

$L_0 = \dfrac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)(x_0-x_3)}$

$L_1 = \dfrac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)}$

$L_2 = \dfrac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}$

$L_3 = \dfrac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}$

Which give:

$L_0=-0.06304, L_1=0.5785, L_2=-0.06185, L_3=0.5460$

Then $P_3(x)=f(x_0)L_0+f(x_1)L_1+f(x_2)L_2+f(x_3)L_3$

Which gives $P_3(x)=0.7313$

What I'd like help with is the error terms, that confuses me still, but it's something like

$\dfrac{f^{(4)}(\epsilon)}{4!} (x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$

What do we do with this?

Comment: In this answer the values of $L_2$ and $L_3$ are exchanged, but probably used in the correct order in the computation of $P_3(x)$. It is also not clear when rounding was applied in what order of operations. Multiplying the quotients and rounding/chopping after each elementary operation I get $L= [-0.06304, 0.5786, 0.5464, -0.06187]$ and $P_3(x)=0.7317$.