# Can you tell me how I get the polynomial to give me 0.7313 when approximating?

Tags: real-analysis

Use the Lagrange interpolating polynomial of degree $3$ and four-digit cut arithmetic to approximate $\cos(0.75)$ by the following values:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\cos(0.698) &= 0.7661, \\ 
\cos(0.733) &= 0.7432, \\ 
\cos(0.768) &= 0.7193, \\ 
\cos(0.803) &= 0.6946 
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

I need to solve this exercise with the code in Python, can someone help me?

This exercise results in $\cos(0.75) \approx 0.7313$,
with real error $0.0004$ and error bound $2.7\times10^{-8}$.

Can you tell me how I get the polynomial to give me 0.7313 when approximating? I have done all the calculations but it gives me 0.7317. The fact is that in Burden's book the solution to the exercise is the one I attach[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHwao.jpg]

Comment: Well, in fact $\cos(.75)=0.731689...$ so I like your answer better (as an approximation, I mean.  I'll check the interpolating polynomial).

Comment: Just ran the interpolation.  I get the same result you do (specifically, I get $.731709$) and given that that is a very accurate value, I think they just have a typo.  My cubic is $0.777454 x^3 - 2.11778 x^2 + 1.182 x + 0.708472$ for comparison

Comment: Or, possibly, they mean for you to use different coefficients.  I am not sure what you mean by "four digit cut arithmetic" but it sounds like it refers to a rounding scheme that you should apply to the coefficients of the cubic.  I did not do that.  Wouldn't surprise me if rounding the coefficient changes the result.

Comment: It exactly refers to the type of rounding but I have tried several times to achieve that result by rounding and everything I have done has been in vain.

Comment: Can you describe the rounding type?  None of my guesses for modifying the coefficients of my cubic gave the desired result.  In any case, this is a question about the rounding mechanism...nothing else.

Comment: There they indicate that the arithmetic be done with a cutoff of 4 digits, the detail is that I don't know when to apply it. I was researching Chapra's numerical analysis book and in the 5th edition solution there is an exercise where they apply arithmetic with cutting on page 22. I have tried to do something similar by truncating the numbers but it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199600/polynomial-interpolation-and-error-bound

Comment: I have tried this way but I don't know what I am doing wrong